# How do I remove last line from text file in C

Tags: c

Here My text file which includes ips :

> 168.897.61.23
>
> 168.32.74.11
>
> 127.0.0.1
>
> 127.0.0.1

here my bad code (sorry i'm newbie) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE *fptr1;
    char file1[] ="test.txt";
    char curr;
    int del, line_number = 0;
    filet = fopen(file1,"r+");
    curr = getc(filet);
    if(curr!=EOF) {line_number =1;}
    while(1){
      if(del != line_number)
        putc(curr, filet);
        curr = getc(filet);
        if(curr =='\n') line_number++;
        if(curr == EOF) break;
    }
    fclose(filet);
}
```

I want working code to output my file like this :

> 168.897.61.23
>
> 168.32.74.11
>
> 127.0.0.1

*Thanks.*

Comment: Seek to the end of the file. Read backwards one character at a time, ignoring any "leading" white-space. Once you hit a newline you know its position. Then either use a system-call to set the end of the file at that position (if available) or read the rest of the file (from the beginning) to the position of the last newline and save it to a new temporary file, and rename the temporary file as the original file.

Comment: where do you assign a value to `del`?

Comment: Did you noticed that ```del``` is uninitialized ?

Comment: `if(curr == EOF)` a `char` cannot hold `EOF` You should use proper type to store return value of `getc`.

Comment: The indentation is weird.  After the undefined behavior at `if(del != line_number)`, do you expect all 4 indented lines to be part of the `if` branch?

Comment: Do you want to delete the last line, or a particular line?  The code seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: Sorry for the errors
@WilliamPursell i want to delete the last line and the output in the same text file .

Comment: Do you mean the last '\n'? Because the lack of newline turns the '\n' into a *delimitor* instead of a *terminator*, which is not POSIX standard and can cause problems. (Newer versions of gcc will warn you about that.) See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline).

Comment: You don't actually want to do any writing at all.  Since you're deleting the last line, you just want to call `truncate`.  The only hard part is reading the file to determine the correct offset.

Comment: eg: https://github.com/wrp/examples/blob/main/c/truncate.c

Comment: @WilliamPursell finally William bravo man that is amazing work fast into the point and thanks for the help.

Comment: @WilliamPursell  i fixed fseeko and ftello ??? but the problem is **truncate keyword** 
GCC : `warning: implicit declaration of function 'truncate' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if( (offset = ftell(in)) == -1 || truncate(path, offset) != 0 ){`

Comment: @HalanoSiblee You need to include `unistd.h`

Comment: @WilliamPursell oh truncate.c work on linux
Can you make truncate.c example for Windows too !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open two distinct files: one for input, another for output

```
FILE *inputfile = fopen("text.txt", "r");
FILE *outputfile = fopen("text-out.txt", "w");
char line1[1000], line2[1000]; // 1000 chars is enough
fgets(line1, sizeof line1, inputfile); // read 1st line and hold on to it

while (fgets(line2, sizeof line2, inputfile)) { // read 2nd (3rd, 4th, ...) line
    fprintf(outputfile, "%s", line1); // print 1st (2nd, 3rd, ...) line
    strcpy(line1, line2); // copy line
}
// last line disappears
fclose(outputfile);
fclose(inputfile);
```

You may now delete the input file and rename the output file if you want to.

```
remove("text.txt");
rename("text-out.txt", "text.txt");
```

Comment: Even better: don't use file names at all. Use `stdin` for the input file and `stdout` for the output.

Comment: it's works ty but please I want the output in the same file
`FILE *inputfile = fopen("text.txt", "r+");`
and my answer be solved
Sorry i'm too weak in this language

Comment: Congratulations on 100k!